# Convert a Radio to a Select

Tags: django, django-forms

I've made my own FieldRenderer like this:

```
class BootstrapRadioFieldRenderer(ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = '<span {id_attr}>{content}</span>'
    inner_html = '<div class="radio">{choice_value}{sub_widgets}</div>'
    choice_input_class = RadioChoiceInput


class BootstrapRadioSelect(RendererMixin, Select):
    renderer = BootstrapRadioFieldRenderer
    _empty_value = ''
```

As you can see it's based on `RadioChoiceInput` which outputs a Radio element. I'd like to change it to output a simple "Select" element. How to do this?

(Of course I've tried to change `RadioChoiceInput` by `Select` and I get `__init__() takes at most 3 arguments (6 given)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what was wrong with me... because the answer was so simple.

I didnt have to touch my model. In all my forms I had things like this:

```
a = _(u'Statut:')
statut = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    label=a, required=False,
    choices=[(k, Personne.TAB_STATUT[k])
             for k in Personne.TAB_STATUT],
    widget=BootstrapRadioSelect(attrs={
        'title': a,
    }),
    error_messages=e)
```

I just had to change them: "back to classical":

```
statut = forms.CharField(
    label=a, required=False,
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'title': a,
        'class': 'form-control'},
        choices=[(k, Personne.TAB_STATUT[k])
                 for k in Personne.TAB_STATUT],),
    error_messages=e)
```

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ChoiceFieldRenderer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4b0118465b485e068a8d9ead2384fcc2ac741f06/django/forms/widgets.py#L672)  is meant to be

> An object used by RadioSelect to enable customization of radio widgets.

however, it does not seem to be useful for customizing a `Select` widget.

To do that, I suggest you subclass [the `Select` widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget) and override it's render method, as [described in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#base-widget-classes).

Alternatively, if you really want to, you can probably define your own `SelectRenderer` which would in turn iterate over `self.choices` of the widget and render them as you intend.

This would be useful if you need more flexibility when defining other subclasses of the widget (where only rendering is modified); I can image other Django users would also benefit of such generic "rendering customization", so feel free to discuss this feature in [the `django-developers` mailing list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/mailing-lists/#django-developers-mailing-list).